# SQL update Query with values coming from other Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm very bad at SQL so I'm struggling to UPDATE using values coming from separate tables:

I need use values inside 2 different tables as well as values from PHP script as part of an update query into a third table. My current SQL

```
UPDATE 
    order1
SET 
    Reorder_Time=supplier.Reorder_Time
    Amount_Ordered="123456789"
    Stock_Amount=product.Stock_Amount
FROM 
    supplier,product
WHERE 
    Order_ID="123456789"
```

:variables is just values from PHP and table and product are just other tables in my database

Comment: We need to understand the relationship between the 3 tables.  You might want to add some sample data.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` on both of your tables and post the results [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71389969/edit)

Comment: ... `FROM supplier,product`  Also, since the FROM clause isn't joining the two tables on anything, you're creating an unintentional [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the php script portion of your question but in order to update a table with the value of another table you might find success using the following `INSERT INTO` statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_abc
SELECT * FROM table_xyz WHERE condition
```

This code assumes that `table_abc` and `table_xyz` have the same structure. SQL will first execute the `SELECT` statement and grab the data that meets the `WHERE` condition. It will then grab those lines and insert them into `table _abc`.

Please try to provide more information on the structure of the 3 tables. The above code will probably not work since it assumes the structure is the same. By structure, I mean same number and names of columns.

Check this out as well: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
update order set 
Reorder_Time=supplier.Reorder_Time
Amount_Ordered="123456789"
Stock_Amount=product.Stock_Amount
from  
order 
join supplier 
on supplier.orderId = order.Id 
join production 
on supplier.[productFK or Id] = product.[Id or supplierFK]
where orderId = 123456789
```

Comment: On MySQL database the order of update with join is `UPDATE table_to_update JOIN other_table ON .... SET .... WHERE ....;`